# How to get Node package size?

Tags: npm, parcel

I'm creating a npm package locally and need to compare the current package built (in node_modules) to the new package (when it gets rebuilt). I'm using Parcel to build my package. Is there a simple way to get the size of an already built npm package? I wanted to log the difference to the console.

I tried using Parcel Bundler Analyzer, but it didn't meet my use case.

Comment: What excactly is your use case? If package size, means "what you have to download when installing from package repo", use `npm pack --dry-run` to get size of tarball.